# JavaScript removes // from URL

Tags: javascript, url

[image]    URL example = new URL(example.getExampleUrl());
    exampleString += "example";

And I have problem with the url that removes `//` from link. So if I have `http://www.google.pl`, I get `http: www.google.pl` instead. I tried with a string, but then I have the same problem. Could anyone tell me how to make this string or url look like a regular link?

its look fine at java http://www.google.pl but at page it is without // so its look http: www.google.pl calendar etc

```
String test = "http://www.google.pl";
<a href="#" onclick="MyWindow=window.open(" 'http:="" www.google.pl','mywindow','width="600,height=600'');">test</a>
```

Answer to this is that there was a problem with " ' in java, i had to use it like that

```
onClick='MyWindow=window.open("+ example +")'

String example= "\"" + google.getUrl()+ "\",\""+google.getNameDisplay()+"\",\"width=600,height=600\"";
```

Comment: why don't you use the string instead of URL, in the script

Comment: couse its work same. and it ends without //

Comment: Please post `example.getExampleUrl()`

Comment: Your code does not remove the // with the given input example.

Comment: Your web page code with the problem is written in JavaScript, not Java.

Answer (score 1):

The toString() method of URL should return just what you want. Try this snippet:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
    URL example = new URL("http://mostmedia.com");
    System.out.println(example.toString());
    assert "http://mostmedia.com".equals(example.toString());

  }
}
```

You can run it on repl.it: https://repl.it/CEVw/1

Comment: At java link look normal , problem is at page.